# Pass function as prop and then pass it as argument to function in ReactJs using functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass function as prop to child comp and then pass it as argument to function in the child component without any luck. I want to set the some value by calling the function setSomeValue(). inside the IncrementValue() function of child component.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

function setSomeValue(val){
    console.log('ur value: ' + val);
}
  return (
    <ChildComponent setSomeValue={setSomeValue} />
);
});
```

Child component Below:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
 function IncrementValue(setSomeValue){
    setSomeValue(6);
 }

function handleClick(){
    IncrementValue(props.setSomeValue);
}
return (
    <button onClick={() => handleClick()}
);
})
```

;

Comment: This code looks OK at a glance. What is not working about it?

Comment: i don't see any problem in your code, it should work. may i know what is the problem ?

Comment: setSomeValue() function is not getting called.. I am trying to find wt is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ur value: ' + value);
    }, [value]);

    function setSomeValue(){
        setValue(value + 1);
    }

    return (
        <ChildComponent value={value} setSomeValue={setSomeValue} />
    );
});


const ChildComponent = ({value, setSomeValue}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <p>Value is: {value}</p>
            <button onClick={setSomeValue}>Increment</button>
        </>
    );
})
```

Comment: hi.. Thanku for the Answer, but my question was , how to pass the function as an arguement to another function in child component and not directly calling it in onclick and plz note that setSome value has a parameter that will be passed from child component.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine apart from small syntax errors. You may want to correct them as shown below and try re-running it again.

```
import React from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const ParentComponent = () => {

  function setSomeValue(val){
      console.log('ur value: ' + val);
  }
  return (
    <ChildComponent setSomeValue={setSomeValue} />
  );
};
```

and the ChildComponent code as:

```
import React from 'react';

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  function IncrementValue(setSomeValue){
     setSomeValue(6);
  }
 
 function handleClick(){
     IncrementValue(props.setSomeValue);
 }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleClick()}/>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```